# Как в Python2.7 повторно использовать sqlite3.Cursor object?

Tags: python, sqlite

Не получается повторно использовать один и тот же sqlite3.Cursor object

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect('comments.db')
>>> c = conn.cursor()
>>> x = c.execute('select id,name from region')
>>> for i in x:
...     print(i)
```

Выводит данные

```
>>> for j in x:
...     print(j)
```

Не выводит данные.

Но ведь переменная "x" - это обычный объект Python, никоим образом не завязанный на СУБД. Не могу понять принцип подобных ограничений. Мне нужно использовать в Python скрипте измененную версию этого объекта, но если он не вызывается повторно, то как это осуществить?

Comment: Почему не завязанный-то, может в цикле он читает строки непосредственно из БД — попытка закрыть БД в цикле ломает цикл и показывает, что так на самом деле и есть. Почему бы вам не собрать все нужные данные в отдельный список и манипулировать им как угодно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте сразу получить все записи в список, тогда можно будет его повторно использовать:

```
items = x.fetchall()
for i in items:
    print(i)

for j in items:
    print(i)
```

Когда вы просто итерировали, то данные возвращались не все сразу, а когда требовалось (представьте что у вас записей 2ккк), смещая и запоминания внутренний указатель, а метод `fetchall` возвращает коллекцию всех запрашиваемых данных.